# Is it possible to copy a command (string) into command line in a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, git

i am actually programming a script where i can store commands in a cheatsheet (e.g. "git add .", "git merge", "docker compose-up" ....) - all commands that i need in my daily work.

see here: https://github.com/m1well/cheatsheet

now i have a question: is it possible to copy a command into the command line without any additional installations?

my actual idea is to implement it like the shell history -> add a number before each command and then i want to call it like this
`$ my-script.sh -c 5`
Where `-c` stands for command parameter (if have several parameters already implemented) and the 5 stands for the command in line 5.

**TL;DR**: is it possible to copy a line from a file to the command line and then execute it by clicking enter?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the OS. For Unix/Linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream) are some suggestions how to stuff some string into the input buffer. Windows is of course different.

A completly different approach based on bash only is using something like this: Type these command into the bash prompt:

```
foo() {
    READLINE_LINE="execute me"
    READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
}
bind -x '"\ex": foo'
```

Now you can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (the `\ex` part int the code) and current input line is replaced with `execute me`.